# how to concatenate and skip rows in google scripts or google Excel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Keep in mind i'm still a beginner to programming, and I work in the medical field. I'm trying to make my own program in google drive (sheets) or through the script editor:

The problem is I'm trying to concatenate strings and skip lines for example:

1. drug1 (cell A1)
2. directions1 (cell A2)
3. disease1 (cell A3)
4. doctor1 (cell A4)
5. drug2 (cell A5)
6. directions2 (cellA6)
7. disease2 (cell A7)
8. doctor2 (cell A8)
9. ...
10. drug5
11. directions5
12. disease5
13. doctor5

I want to convert that column into this:

1. Drug1 directions1 (Cell B1)
2. Drug2 directions2 (Cell B2)
3. ...
4. Drug5 directions5 (cell B3)

So that I can copy and paste column B into a document for better formatting.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
   function myfunction() {

  for(i=1; i<=8; i+4)
  {
   var part1 = "=ARRAYFORMULA(Concatenate(A";
   var part2 = i;
   var part3 = ", ,A";
   var part4 = i + 1; 
   var part5 = "))";
   var part5 = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4 + part5; 
   return part5;
  }
}
```

it only works for cella1 and cella2

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? Please add your code as [mcve] and explain what is not working as intended in it.

Comment: Do you have more than 5 instances that you want to concatenate?  If it is only 5, it would be much easier to just use the `concatenate` formula in the cells you want, rather than creating the formula programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B1:

```
=QUERY({A1:A8,A2:A9},"Select Col1,Col2 skipping 4",0)
```

- Arrange arrays overlapping each other using `{}`
- Query to skip 4 rows each time